# Generate one html or pdf page from a series of php-created html pages

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I created a php script that dynamically creates a series of html pages (each exact A4 size) based on the user selecting several components to make the page such as background image, logos to place on top or at the bottom and different pieces of text translated by Google.

The layout is quite complex with a few div placed at exact position on the A4 page.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/245732172a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <style>     
 html, body, div, p, li { margin:0; font-family:Calibri; color:#858484; }
 .div-edit, .div-edit a, .div-edit a:link, .div-edit a:visited { font-size:0.9em; color:white; }
 .div-link, .div-link a, .div-link a:link, .div-link a:visited { font-size:{!! $page->font_size_link !!}em; color:white; text-align:center; }
 .div-strip { color:white; font-size:{!! $page->font_size_strip !!}em; font-weight:bold; text-align:center; z-index: 10; }
 h1 { color:#f7a600; font-size:{!! $page->font_size_title !!}em; font-weight:normal; }
 h2 { color:#858484; font-weight:bold; font-size:{!! $page->font_size_subtitle !!}em; }
 strong, .scStrong { font-weight:bold; color:#f7a600; }
 li { font-size:{!! $page->font_size_criteria !!}em; }
 li::marker { content:"✓  "; color:#f7a600; }
 
 .container { position:relative; background-image:url('{{ $page->layout }}'); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:contain; width:210mm; height:297mm; padding:0; }
 .div-edit { position:absolute; top:0mm; left:37mm; width:173mm; height:8mm; padding:0; background-color:grey; text-align:right; padding-top:2mm; }
 .div-logo { background-image:url('{{ $page->logo }}'); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:contain; }
 .div-logo { position:absolute; top:{{ $pdf['yLogo'] }}mm; left:{{ $pdf['xLogo'] }}mm; width:{{ $pdf['wLogo'] }}mm; height:{{ $pdf['hLogo'] }}mm; padding:0; }
 .div-body { position:absolute; top:18mm; left:48mm; width:150mm; height:250mm; padding:0; }
 .spacer { float:right; width:100mm; height:50mm; background:transparent; shape-outside:polygon(100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0 0%); }
 h1 { margin:0; padding-top:0mm; padding-right:0mm; }
 h2 { margin:0; padding-top:6mm; padding-bottom:6mm; padding-right:0mm; }
 .div-logos { background-image:url('{{ $page->logos }}'); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:contain; }
 .div-logos { position:absolute; top:270mm; left:48mm; width:150mm; height:14mm; padding:0; }
 .div-link { position:absolute; top:285mm; left:48mm; width:150mm; height:5mm; padding:0; }
 .div-strip { position: absolute; top:19.5mm; left:51mm; width:200mm; height:20mm; padding:0; 
     -ms-transform: rotate(27deg);
     -webkit-transform: rotate(27deg); 
     -moz-transform: rotate(27deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(27deg);
     -sand-transform: rotate(27deg);
     transform: rotate(27deg);
 }
 .container { border:1px solid grey; }
 </style>
 </head>
 
 <body>
 <div class="container">
         
     <div class="div-logo"></div>
 
     <div class="div-body">
         <div class="spacer"></div>
         <h1>{!! $page->title !!}</h1>
         <h2>{!! $page->subtitle !!}</h2>
         {!! $page->body !!}
     </div>
 
     <div class="div-logos"></div>
 
     <div class="div-link">
         {!! $page->link !!}
     </div>
 
     <div class="div-strip">
         {!! $page->strip !!}
     </div>
      
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

An example can been seen [here](https://www.utopia-africa.com/tools/viewSC?u=1&l=ST&id=3&logo=logo_UC.png).

The ideal output is that the user gets a series of PDFs to be downloaded as a zip file.  The problem is none of the free PHP/HTML-to-PDF packages are doing a good job at a complex layout.

Another idea would be to combine all the dynamically generated HTML pages into one big HTML page that the user could print as a PDF.  Not even sure if that would work with the absolute positioning of the divs...

I also tried the html2canvas but I got stuck at the second part... could not figure out how to send the data to the php script on laravel.  This method seemed promising but I could not see the result.

```
 <script src="html2canvas.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 window.onload = () => html2canvas(document.body).then(canvas => {
   // CANVAS TO FORM DATA
   var data = new FormData();
   data.append("img", canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
  
   // UPLOAD TO 2B-SAVE.PHP
   fetch("2b-save.php", { method:"post", body:data })
   .then(res => res.text())
   .then(txt => console.log(txt));
 });
```

Last I looked at the browser headless web service but nothing is really for free and this project is for a NGO...

So I would really appreciate some feedback on the matter...

Comment: Another solution is a variation of your print HTML to PDF idea. Instead of one large file, use pagination where each button will navigate the user to a different page where they can print that one to a PDF. And just use CSS to hide the pagination buttons from the printer.

Comment: Please focus on the main parts - is this a PHP problem (on your server), or an HTML, JS, or CSS problem (in the browser)?

Comment: @NicoHaase There are several options using different techniques (as you listed them... PHP problem (on your server), or an HTML, JS, or CSS)... which one is the easiest giving the best results... that is exactly the purpose of my question.